# Maven isn't working with specifying Java JDK?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to specify which Java JDK version to use in Maven/IntelliJ IDEA. I want to use JDK 7, but the source always seems to compile in JDK 8. I have done quite a few things, this is the screenshot of my Project Structure settings of IntelliJ IDEA:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wabk2.png

This is my pom.xml. As you can see, I am using properties, and the maven compiler plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-          4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>me.staticjava</groupId>
<artifactId>VillagerMerchants</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.md-5.net/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9-R0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>craftbukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9-R0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am not sure why, but the code ALWAYS compiles in 1.8...

Any help?

Thanks,
~StaticJava

Comment: What do you get when you run `mvn --version` on the console?

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/d87a30f40436588c116d585ead85e0e7.png @user432

Comment: Did you specify a different jdk using java_home in intellij? To check run the same command in the ide.

Comment: @Hannes As run in IntelliJ: http://i.gyazo.com/6bef83e708f650f802cf85ac9aa78d3e.png

Comment: How do you know that your code compiles in 1.8?

Comment: Well, I am not sure. This is my manifest: http://i.gyazo.com/570adfb61c10ff3771078fafe65a3f8f.png But then, I used a utility called Jarcheck, and get this: http://i.gyazo.com/149a37fb1c27293d21a44a4ce64f80f5.png @user432

Comment: My guess would be the tool is not working as intended. You can watch the sourcecode [here](http://wush.net/svn/mindprod/com/mindprod/jarcheck/JarCheck.java) and see for yourself if you want to trust it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into `Settings` -> `Project Settings` -> `Maven` -> `Runner` and check the `JRE` setting.

Mine is set to *Use Project JDK (1.7)* but it sounds like yours is set to something different.

By the way, I guess you are aware that the "language level" in your pom (1.7) is a different setting to the actual JDK you compile with. For example you can well use JDK 1.8 but compile to language level java 7... :)

Good luck.